# Any way to fix Jenkins server?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, devops

Whenever I try to access my Jenkins UI @ localhost:8080, it shows a bare white screen saying “it works!” And even when I uninstall and reinstall, delete files, it still shows the “it works message”, I seen some files were missing and the hidden Jenkins directory is no longer present

Comment: You need to provide more details for us to understand your issue. Please go through this and add relevant details. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.